# Custom Keybindings not working

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I had to reinstall emacs and completely redo my config file, but for some reason, some of the custom keybindings that used to work with "move-dup" package from Melpa. Here is what i have:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
(require 'move-dup)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") 'md-move-lines-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<down>") 'md-move-lines-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<up>") 'md-duplicate-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<down>") 'md-duplicate-down)
#+end_src>
```

What would stop these from working?
EDIT: so this does work, if i enable move-dup-mode, however I can't seem to get it to be enabled on start up, I've tried adding the following but it still doesn't load on startup:

```
(move-dup-mode 1)
```

I've also tried:

```
(global-move-dup-mode 1)
```

and I've also tried replacing the '1' for a 't' in on each one too, but to no avail. How can I get this to load on startup please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have either a `(require 'move-dup)` or a `use-package` declaration for `move-dup`? If not, that is likely your problem.

Comment: Yes it is in there, I just moved it to the top of the config file just under use melpa part, and then added (global-move-dup 1) up to the top of the page also and it all came to life and now does work. Thanks for your input, I'm going to give you a solved.

Comment: it sounds as though there is an error in your init file and so everything after that is not being loaded. Check the message you get after you open emacs.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, this is what I suspected, moving it up worked for me for the moment, and everything else loads fine, so I may well have fixed it by mistake, not ideal, but it all works now.